# Multiple LineLayer Colour doesn't change in the ShapeSource

Tags: react-native, dictionary, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have use the MapBox to draw multiple lines with different coordinate, So I use the ShapeSource layer and LineLayer for this, Currently I have take one ShapeSource layer in it. and add two line layer, The line should different color but in map it's display only single color.

**One line layer color should red and other should green.**

Code ::

```
let featureCollection = [
  {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: { color: "red" },
    geometry: {
      type: "LineString",
      coordinates: [
        [1.023194, 7.946528],
        [0.93005, 8.554639],
        [1.431726, 8.61838],
        [1.483318, 9.000202],
        [2.005096, 9.002147],
        [2.583486, 9.396939],
        [2.439416, 9.782727],
        [2.718134, 10.336571],
        [2.760431, 11.092622],
        [3.587083, 11.990781],
        [3.544915, 12.64725],
        [3.74451, 13.056562],
        [3.902861, 13.039418],
        [4.411557, 13.622376],
        [4.932224, 13.788399],
        [4.736514, 14.462161],
        [5.25854, 14.90048],
        [5.336759, 15.593429],
        [5.800658, 15.903908],
        [5.753171, 16.280243],
        [6.125972, 17.373351],
        [6.061882, 18.806859],
        [5.773197, 19.505027],
        [5.780191, 20.844999],
        [5.428159, 22.666003],
        [5.713896, 22.944738],
        [5.763205, 23.654738],
        [7.397073, 25.060067],
        [7.352812, 25.732464],
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: { color: "green" },
    geometry: {
      type: "LineString",
      coordinates: [
        [27.84931, -13.133984],
        [28.226637, -12.537425],
        [27.558161, -11.638463],
        [27.952453, -11.129576],
        [27.204369, -9.244411],
        [27.238034, -7.792886],
        [26.13459, -7.455348],
        [25.428301, -6.254818],
        [24.482978, -5.97556],
        [24.275024, -3.06516],
        [23.407, -2.22699],
        [23.393044, -1.333777],
        [22.269193, -0.586803],
        [22.457468, 0.68996],
        [20.968402, 1.779982],
        [21.521327, 2.142979],
        [21.454121, 2.947052],
        [20.75021, 2.814715],
        [19.392839, 4.146715],
        [18.58327, 4.357795],
        [18.651652, 5.052913],
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

MapBox ::

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
        styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Light}
        zoomLevel={2}
        centerCoordinate={[22.9375, 30.5595]}
        // centerCoordinate={[72.586952, 23.16729]}
        style={{
          height: deviceHeight,
          width: deviceWidth,
        }}
      >
        <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
          id="line"
          shape={{
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: featureCollection,
          }}
        >
          {featureCollection.map((item) => {
            return (
              <MapboxGL.LineLayer
                id={"linelayer"}
                style={{
                  lineJoin: "round",
                  lineColor: item.properties.color,
                  lineWidth: 5,
                  lineCap: "round",
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
      </MapboxGL.MapView>
```

Output ::

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `LineLayer` to draw both the lines, and you need to use a [data-driven property](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-lines/) to grab the color from your feature collection and use it.

```
<MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Light}>
  <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="line" shape={feature}>
    <MapboxGL.LineLayer
      id={"linelayer"}
      style={{
        lineJoin: "round",
        lineColor: ["get", "color"],
        lineWidth: 5,
        lineCap: "round",
      }}
    />
  </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```